# Drupal 7 double lined menu

Tags: php, css, menu, drupal-7

I am developing a site with Drupal 7. I have styled the menu correctly and all this stuff. The problem is with the secondary menu.

My idea is to create the second menu immediatly behind the first menu, for example:

**MENU_ITEM1** |  MENU_ITEM2  |  MENU_ITEM3   |  MENU_ITEM4

MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM1   |  MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM2   |    MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM3

And the structure goes like this:

- MENU_ITEM1

  - MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM1
  - MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM2
  - MENU_ITEM1_SUBITEM3
- MENU_ITEM2
- MENU_ITEM3
- MENU_ITEM4

1st problem, I cannot see secondary items
2nd Any suggestion on how to create this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't have any experience with Drupal...but that doesn't change the fact that I don't understand what your problem is...  Are you asking how to create [unordered lists](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all drupal themes allow you to style your menus like this.

If you have a theme that supports nested menu structures, you just need to nest your menu items in the menu settings. Fortunately, drupal handles this relatively well thanks to the drag and drop interface, you just need to make sure that any of your top level menu items have the "expanded" box checked.

If you would like to see a quick example, you can just look at your "navigation" menu settings, they are already nested and expanded, so you'll know what your main menu settings should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your menu with multiple levels within drupal, and select that menu *(e.g. main menu)* as the **source for both** your **main links** and **secondary links**, over at *"/admin/structure/menu/settings"*.

Then you can implement drupal's **theme_preprocess_page()** function in your **template.php** file:

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (isset($vars['main_menu'])) {
        $vars['primary_links'] = theme('links__system_primary_menu', array(
            'links' => $vars['main_menu'],
        ));
    }
    else {
        $vars['primary_links'] = false;
    }

    if (isset($vars['secondary_menu'])) {
        $vars['secondary_links'] = theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
            'links' => $vars['secondary_menu'],
        ));
    }
    else {
        $vars['primary_links'] = false;
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is echo/print the new variables (`$primary_links` & `$secondary_links` in this case) now available to **page.tpl.php**.